# Returned non-zero exit status 2 gdal_merge.py in QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, qgis-plugins, gdal-merge

I'm trying to merge several files within a QGIS plugin via gdal_merge.py. In Anaconda distribution exactly the same code works as it is like that. I suppose Python in QGIS can't find gdal_merge.py. But maybe I'm also wrong. How can I fix this issue?

```
wd = C:/Users/Jonas/Documents/Bachelorarbeit/MODIS/Data/oneday
# Define directories
Path(wd+"/mergedTiles").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
out_dir = wd + '/mergedTiles/'

# Get tif files in wd
tile_list = glob.glob(wd+'/unmergedTiles' + '/*LST_*.tiff')

#get sublsists and zip
str_start = [s.split('\\')[1][:17] for s in tile_list]
str_end = [s.split('\\')[1].split('_')[1] for s in tile_list]
res = np.unique([i + j for i, j in zip(str_start, str_end)])

for label in res: 
    files = [wd+'/unmergedTiles/' + s.split('\\')[1] for s in tile_list if s.endswith(label[17:]) and s.split('\\')[1][:17] == label[:17]]
    out_path = out_dir + label
    #print('Files To Merge')
    #print(files)
    cmd = 'python ' + "gdal_merge.py" +' -co COMPRESSED=YES'+ ' -o' + ' ' + out_path + ' ' + '-of gtiff ' + " ".join(files)
    #print(cmd)
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Comment: Did you try just `gdal_merge.py` instead of `python gdal_merge.py`? Normally, if it's in the path, you don't need to explicitly add `python`. If no choice, you may `import os` and `os.chdir(path_to_dir_containing_gdal_merge)`

Comment: @ThomasG77 if I delete "python in my string I get a new error.  OSError: [WinError 193] is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: in addition, I have differnt gdal_merge.py in QGIS and anaconda. I actually don't know to which I shoud refer.

Comment: Use the 2nd recipe in my comment and don't remove `python` as it's breaking. About choosing one or the other gdal_merge.py. If your QGIS is not executed from a conda env, use the QGIS gdal_merge.py

Comment: it has worked! Adter trying some directories. Thanks for help